# Python ,SQLAlchemy, get id from database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to make a Python (SQLAlchemy) program that takes the ID from a table according to a value.

For example, I have a table like this :

```
-------------------------------
|     ID       |     Name     |
-------------------------------
|     1        |     Paul     |
-------------------------------
|     2        |     Paul     |
-------------------------------
|     3        |     John     |
-------------------------------
```

And I want to retrieve the IDs where the name is Paul.

The code I was doing was something like this :

```
list = session.query(Table).filter_by(Name='Paul')
list_id = []
for tuple in list :
   list_id.append(tuple.id)
for id in list_id :
   print(id)
```

Is there any much easier solution?

Thanks!

Comment: aside, `list`, `tuple` and `id` are builtins,  Shadowing them like this is bad form; consider using `PaulQuery` `PaulRow` and `Paul.id`.  In case you really do want the same name as a builtin, `list_`, `tuple_` or `id_` might still be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate list to 'hold' the id, if you only use them once, just iterate directly over the query.

```
for row in session.query(Table).filter_by(Name='Paul'):
   print(row.ID)
```

If you only need the ID, you can arrange for your query to return only that:

```
for ID in session.query(Table.ID).filter_by(Name='Paul'):
   print(ID)
```